# Adding Padding Between Menu Items - Shopify Sub Menu

Tags: html, css, menu, shopify

I'd like to have a submenu on my Shopify 'About Us' page. So far I have set up the menu, using the following steps; Online Store > Navigation > Add Menu > about-us-menu

I worked out how to display said menu using the code below, I have inserted this directly into the page template:

```
<div class="site-nav__item">    
{% for link in linklists.about-us-menu.links %}
<a href="{{ link.url }}"> {{ link.title }}</a>
{% endfor %}
```

All of the menu items are bunched together and this looks stupid. How do I add padding between the menu items, while ensuring that it looks good on both desktop and mobile? I assume I use CSS?

I have already tried to use the following (which had no impact):

```
padding-right: 25px !important;
```

Or am I approaching this in the wrong way? I also tried using tabs, which I didn't like the look of (maybe I need some better CSS?) and tried an invisible table (which looked terrible on mobile).

Thanks for any help.

Guy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try using inline style on a tag. let us know if that works and we can investigate further

```html
<a style='padding-right:25px' href='www.stackoverflow.com'>stack</a>
<a href='www.stackoverflow.com'>stack</a>
```

Comment: I tried this by adding the code here: <div class="site-nav__item">    
   {% for link in linklists.about-us-menu.links %}
 <style='padding-right:25px' a href="{{ link.url }}"> {{ link.title }}</a>
{% endfor %}

No joy though. Link is https://iron-mills.co.uk/pages/about-us

Comment: add the padding to 
.site-nav__item  also it should be <a style='padding-right:25px'  href=" not <style='padding-right:25px' a href="